# Database and Windows device application communication with Windows Firewall enable

Tags: c#, windows-firewall

I have a `C#` program running on a mobile device. The current program makes transcations with an `MS SQL 2008 Express Server` on a `Windows 7` machine.

As long as the `Windows Firewall` is off the comminucation runs smoothly. Once I open the Firewall (as expected) communication is interupted.
The server port is configured on port 1433. I add an outbound rule to the Firewall for port 1433 but still not getting a result.

The thing is I must have the Firewall enabled on this machine, so I must find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well....

> The server port is configured on port 1433. I add an outbound rule to the Firewall for port 
>   1433 but still not getting a result.

Because a database server does not try to reach machines on the network. It LISTENS.

So, instead of an OUTBOUND rule, make it an INBOUND rule for TCP 1433 and it will magically work. Because it is the other machine (your mobile device) that is reaching INTO the server (and opening the connection), not the server trying to find the mobile device somewhere on the big dark and unfriendly internet.